# react super, Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, es6-class

i try to use and overwrite a parent method in child one but get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

[image]

```
class BreadcrumbsHome extends React.Component {
  getBreadcrumbs = () => [{name: 'home', url: '/'}];

  render() {
    return <nav>
      <ol className="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
        {!!this.getBreadcrumbs && this.getBreadcrumbs().map((e, i, arr) =>
          <li className={`breadcrumb-item ${i === arr.length - 1 ? 'active' : ''}`}><a
            href={APP_CONTEXT + e.url}>{e.name}</a>/</li>
        )}
      </ol>
    </nav>
  }
}

class BreadcrumbsTypes extends BreadcrumbsHome {

  getBreadcrumbs = () => [
    ...super.getBreadcrumbs(),
    ...this.props.path
  ]
```

as i read about this problem. Seems to be tied with babel so i tried adding the `//noprotect` line

I would like to handle with ES6 and avoid such way
`ParentClass.prototype.myMethod.call(this, arg1, arg2, ..)`

Any ideas to fix that?

Comment: field initializers are own properties, not inherited. You're not over-riding the base class's implementation, you're over-_writing_ it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks, i fixed that )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to maintain the typical virtual polymorphism expected in JavaScript prototypal inheritance, you can't use field initializer syntax, you must use the ES2015 class method syntax:

```
class BreadcrumbsHome extends React.Component {
  getBreadcrumbs () {
    return [{ name: 'home', url: '/' }];
  }

  render() {
    return <nav>
      <ol className="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
        {this.getBreadcrumbs().map((e, i, { length }) => (
          <li
            key={`${e.name}-${e.url}`}
            className={`breadcrumb-item ${i === length - 1 ? 'active' : ''}`}
          >
            <a href={APP_CONTEXT + e.url}>{e.name}</a> /
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </nav>
  }
}

class BreadcrumbsTypes extends BreadcrumbsHome {

  getBreadcrumbs () {
    return [
      ...super.getBreadcrumbs(),
      ...this.props.path
    ];
  }

  ...
}
```

The problem is that field initializers create own properties on each class instance rather than binding to the prototype chain like class methods do, so all you were doing was overwriting the own property `getBreadcrumbs` initialized by the base class with the own property initialized by the extended class.

You can confirm this using a debugger console:

[image] vs. [image]

P.S. don't forget to include a unique `key` property on mapped JSX components :)

I'd also suggest using CSS to style `.breadcrumb-item:last-child` rather than `.breadcrumb-item.active`, so your `map()` callback can simplify the `className` to

```
className="breadcrumb-item"
```

You can also add the following class to your CSS

```
.breadcrumb-item::after { 
  content: "/";
}
```

so you can omit the `/` in your JSX.

Comment: Super helpful explanation, thanks. I find it a little disturbing that developers have to choose between having bound methods (field initializer syntax + arrow fn) OR virtual methods (class method syntax). Seems like a great opportunity for access modifiers (i.e. `virtual` and could go even as far as `bound`).

Comment: @Keego The method is either an own property of the class or of the instance. If it's an own property of the class, it can't be bound, because it has to respect the `this` context passed to it via method call. If it's an own property of the instance, it can't be virtual because the dispatch via `super` from a derived class will not find the method on the base class. Could potentially be a syntax to create an own property on both the class and the instance, but I personally feel that syntax would be a footgun since majority of use-cases won't require both behaviors at once (and it's expensive).

Answer (score 1):

In Short

#### Do not use arrow function

```
class Child extends Parent {

+  getBreadcrumbs(){}
-  getBreadcrumbs = () => {}
}
```